# How do i fix values must be a 1D array problem in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df["TROL10"].values
```

I get this which seems to me that its a 1D array. Do you have any ideas?

```
[18.604038230955343, 18.670614362306086, 18.646735605154216,
 18.656236215707576,  18.53352615271398, 18.537702884272235,
 18.448225333878803, 18.355757101875124,  18.20601450637466,
 18.160600591544057,  18.13380762932929, 18.034593494718145,
 17.950137698176437,  17.87131617610324,  17.87661036759285,
 17.791582399374334, 17.840878239393277,  17.77368955956415,
 17.712932564513817, 17.593807522663035, 17.528720974631437,
 17.569683995275437, 17.495345618314875,  17.45466774254079,
 17.429889960592973, 17.494336028145792, 17.532905610808747,
 17.503039219365693,   17.5860857196472, 17.780398532824318,
 17.909579658472524, 17.870647851379257,  17.95176205667108,
 18.005518826259493, 18.126175175198767, 18.211852627985856,
 18.349079574880196, 18.495299900821262, 18.547974301845898,
 18.491714065403823,  18.43596777154002, 18.434644986531357,
 18.464600010234033, 18.514984547670664, 18.514486649449985,
 18.529428325473493, 18.524350534809535, 18.446600412835394,
 18.447354325389387, 18.577178082191782, 18.638549071120305,
 18.801725876448224,  18.85516122233934, 18.970825102659326,
 19.028430552743707, 19.016882970334628, 18.986930728672984,
 19.122546933524852,   19.1271569632681,  19.10994756706495,
  19.35443247582892, 19.303999834778512,  19.45680060316427,
  19.40531602255797,  19.72797110743794, 19.545107804925124]
Length: 66, dtype: Float64
```

and then when after the following line I get the `ValueError` and I'm sure that the `df["DATE"]` isn't causing the problem because I have already used that earlier with zero problems.

```
plt.plot(df['DATE'], df["TROL10"])
```

and i get
ValueError: values must be a 1D array

Comment: The values in one column of  a DataFrame (i.e. a pandas.Series) are supposed to be 1D array. What ValueError are you getting at which line? Please post the complete error traceback. Also, what is your question?

Comment: @Marcel the .to_numpy() seems to work, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data plots ok.

```
array=np.array([18.604038230955343, 18.670614362306086, 18.646735605154216,
```

18.656236215707576,  18.53352615271398, 18.537702884272235,
18.448225333878803, 18.355757101875124,  18.20601450637466,
18.160600591544057,  18.13380762932929, 18.034593494718145,
17.950137698176437,  17.87131617610324,  17.87661036759285,
17.791582399374334, 17.840878239393277,  17.77368955956415,
17.712932564513817, 17.593807522663035, 17.528720974631437,
17.569683995275437, 17.495345618314875,  17.45466774254079,
17.429889960592973, 17.494336028145792, 17.532905610808747,
17.503039219365693,   17.5860857196472, 17.780398532824318,
17.909579658472524, 17.870647851379257,  17.95176205667108,
18.005518826259493, 18.126175175198767, 18.211852627985856,
18.349079574880196, 18.495299900821262, 18.547974301845898,
18.491714065403823,  18.43596777154002, 18.434644986531357,
18.464600010234033, 18.514984547670664, 18.514486649449985,
18.529428325473493, 18.524350534809535, 18.446600412835394,
18.447354325389387, 18.577178082191782, 18.638549071120305,
18.801725876448224,  18.85516122233934, 18.970825102659326,
19.028430552743707, 19.016882970334628, 18.986930728672984,
19.122546933524852,   19.1271569632681,  19.10994756706495,
19.35443247582892, 19.303999834778512,  19.45680060316427,
19.40531602255797,  19.72797110743794, 19.545107804925124])

```
x=np.linspace(1,len(array),len(array))
plt.plot(x,array)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see it now. Are you using `pandas.array` to create the columns of the DataFrame? If you use `numpy` arrays instead it should work as you expect.

You can also call `.to_numpy()` on the `pandas` arrays.